# How can i push into schema array of mongoose?Initial array is empy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

## I want to update array of objects - profiles by using input [image]

I use express,mongoose in reactjs. I have schema --

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const validator = require("validator");
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 4,
    unique: true,
    validate: {
      validator(email) {
        return validator.isEmail(email);
      },
    },
},
  password:{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    select: false,
  },
  profiles:[ // array of user's profile
    {
      type:ObjectId,
      name:String,
    }
  ]

})
```

this is my route ---

```js
router.post('/createProfile', createProfile);
```

what i tryed ---

```js
module.exports.createProfile = (req,res) =>{
  
  const {name} = req.body;
  console.log(name)
  User.push(profiles,name)
  .then((result)=>res.send(result))
  .catch((err)=>console.log(err))

}
```

I dont know what the coreect way to use push. Do i need to use push? Is my chema for profiles OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you specified in your schema that `profiles` field is of type `array of ObjectIds`. It looks like you want it to be of type `String` instead, since you are trying the push the `name` inside.

So, you should first change your Schema model:

```js
profiles:[ // array of user's profile
  {
    type: String,
  }
]
```

Now, you can push new items to that array like this:

```js
User.updateOne(
  { _id: req.user._id },
  { $push: { profiles: name } }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the %push operator in moongose

```
module.exports.createProfile = (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.body;

  User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.user._id },  
    { $push: { profiles: { name } } },
    { new: true, useFindAndModify: false }  
  )
  .then((result) => res.send(result))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
};
```

the `findOneAndUpdate` function is used to find user. and update it .as you asked

Comment: But if i have nothing inside my array before? I tryed your seggestion, i don't know why but its doesn work.